# Slice automatically be sorted?

Tags: go

While I want to create my own pipeline to practice with goroutines, there's something particularly weird.
I use the random perm function to generate some int numbers, randomly obviously, I write them to IO writer and then read them form IO reader, cuz its binary source so I print them and they are sorted!!

Here's the code:

```
func RandomSource(tally int) chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    sli := rand.Perm(tally)
    fmt.Println(sli)
    go func() {
        for num := range sli {
            out <- num
        }
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}
```

```
func ReaderSource(reader io.Reader) chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        buffer := make([]byte, 8)
        for ; ; {
            n, err := reader.Read(buffer)
            if n > 0 {
                v := int(binary.BigEndian.Uint64(buffer))
                out <- v
            }
            if err != nil {
                break
            }
        }
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}
```

```
func WriterSink(writer io.Writer, in chan int) {
    for v := range in {
        buffer := make([]byte, 8)
        binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(
            buffer, uint64(v))
        writer.Write(buffer)
    }
}
```

```
func main() {
    fileName := "small.in"
    file, err := os.Create(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    p := RandomSource(500)
    WriterSink(file, p)

    file, err = os.Open(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    p = ReaderSource(file)
    for v := range p {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please rephrase it.

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/16

Comment: Function random.Perm() generates a slice, random numbers obviously, try to iterate through the slice, they are in order, why?

Answer (score 5):

`range` returns an index as the first value for an array or slice, which always goes from 0 up to `len - 1`. Use `for _, num := range sli {` if you want to iterate over the values themselves rather than the set of indices.

Comment: I know that I mean the function random.Perm() generate some random values, unordered, but I while I iterate through the slice, they are in order!